# grab.error.GrabTimeoutError [Errno 28] Resolving timed out after 3000 milliseconds

Tags: python, grab

```
from grab import Grab
g = Grab()
resp = g.go('http://yandex.ru/')
```

[Здесь](https://github.com/lorien/grab/issues/140) говорят об ошибке DNS. [Кому-то](http://www.cyberforum.ru/python/thread1632257.html) удалось исправить при помощи переустановки pycurl. Пробовал переустановить разными способами. Результата нет. Python 35 Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

Столкнулся с этой же проблемой. Переустановки pycurl результатов не принесли.
Проблема похоже с очерёдностью сетевых интерфейсов в Windows:

```
C:\Windows\system32>netsh interface show interface
```

Отключите все интерфейсы, кроме основного, через который обращаетесь в Интернет, и проблема должна уйти. Похоже curl выбирает интерфейс для DNS запросов по своей логике... возможно просто выбирает первый по номеру интерфейс в Windows и пытается работать через него. Досконально не разбирался...

Answer (score 1):

Отключил в свойствах сети Протокол Интернета версии 6 (TCP/Ipv6) и всё заработало